# How to Install ALL python3.5 Dependencies on Ubuntu

Tags: dependencies, python3, system

I have removed and purged python3.5 and all its dependencies with the command hereafter, which subsequently broke my Ubuntu installation (I thought that I could use python3.7 instead, but realized afterwards that numerous Ubuntu components rely on python3.5). I was able to recover it by re-installing python3.5 and the Ubuntu Desktop.

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge python3.5
```

My question is, by reinstalling python3.5 and the Desktop, will this re-install all the python3.5 dependencies? Is there a specific command I can launch to make sure that all dependencies are installed?

Thank you. J

Comment: Thank you user535733. Correct, the answer has help me recover my installation. I was wondering however if all the dependencies will have been installed with the re-installation of python3.5.

Comment: Apt automatically installs all *required* dependencies. Making dependencies easy is apt's purpose. Apt has no idea what non-required (optional) packages you may have previously installed.

Comment: Thank you user535733!